# Generalizing the Pythagorean trig identity $\sin^2{\theta}+\cos^2{\theta}=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, power-series

The following is a generalization of the half-angle formulas presented at [Nabla - Applications of Trigonometry](http://www.nabla.hr/GE-AppTrigonomB1.htm) for a triangle.

**Generalization**. Let $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ be the sides of a general convex quadrilateral, $s$ is the semiperimeter, and  $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ are opposite angles, then

> $$ad\sin^2{\frac{\alpha}{2}}+bc\cos^2{\frac{\gamma}{2}}=(s-a)(s-d).\tag{1}$$

For a proof of $(1)$ see pp.8 [here](http://matinf.upit.ro/MATINF6/RevistaMATINF_6.pdf).

In $(1)$, consider the case when $a=c$, $b=d$ and $\alpha=\gamma$ so that the quadrilateral is a parallelogram . Then

$$ab\sin^2{\frac{\alpha}{2}}+ab\cos^2{\frac{\alpha}{2}}=\frac{-a+b+c+d}{2}\cdot{\frac{a+b+c-d}{2}}=ab.$$
Dividing both sides by $ab$ you get

$$\sin^2{\frac{\alpha}{2}}+\cos^2{\frac{\alpha}{2}}=1.$$

Or by making $\frac{\alpha}{2}=\theta$,

> $$\sin^2{\theta}+\cos^2{\theta}=1,$$

which is the [Pythagorean trigonometric identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_trigonometric_identity).

**a) Does $(1)$ also generalize the Pythagorean trig identity or am I fooling myself?**

**b) In the Wikipedia page for the PTI, there is a [proof that uses power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_trigonometric_identity#Proof_using_power_series), [a proof that uses differential equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_trigonometric_identity#Proof_using_the_differential_equation) and [a proof that uses the Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_trigonometric_identity#Proof_using_Euler%27s_formula). I wonder if any of these proofs could be generalized to prove $(1)$.**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137645/discussion-on-question-by-emmanuel-jose-garcia-generalizing-the-pythagorean-trig).

Comment: The conversation is not gone, just moved to chat. [ChatJax](http://tinyurl.com/cfqcvpc) is useful for reading MathJax in chat.

Comment: @robjohn: I don't see the point of making it more difficult for readers to access an *already finished* discussion when there are lots of more extended discussion out there.

Comment: @EmmanuelJoséGarcía The philosophy of the SE network is that comments are [temporary "Post-It" notes](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).  They are meant to offer suggestions or clarifications to the poster, so that problems with a question or answer can be fixed via editing.  Once a conversation has "finished" (as you say), the standard procedure would be to *delete* those comments (without moving them to chat).  If something in a comment needs to be preserved, edit it into the question, or write an answer based on that material.